Antlr4: Change token type in token recognition error
Using c++ During a token recognition error in the antlr4 Lexer how can I set a token type to it?
for eg. in the Lexer file I can add
@lexer::members {  
    enum {
        UNKNOWN_TOKEN = INT_MAX
    }
}

And when a token recognition error occurs, I can set it to UNKNOWN_TOKEN.
I'd like to do this because I'm using the antlr grammar for syntax highlighting a gerebr file
The visitor is used to analyze the data in the file and the lexer is extended with a member that uses getAllTokens() for colorizing the text.
I already highlight other errors and deprecated lines in the file by using
void syntaxError(antlr4::Recognizer* recognizer, antlr4::Token* offendingSymbol, size_t line, size_t charPositionInLine, const std::string& msg, std::exception_ptr e)  in the BaseErrorListner
During a token recognition error offendingSymbol is a nullptr so it isn't really useful.
I have tried to use a catch all block in the lexer by doing
//All other stuff...

//End of default_mode.
UNKNOWN_TOKEN : .+?;

//Other modes...

but that messes with the parsing in unpredictable ways.
Even otherwise, I'd like to not use a catch-all block.

Antlr4 does not allow you to assign an integer to a token type. You have to declare the token type with a "tokens spec" tokens { FOOBAR } before the lexer rules. Then, in a lexer rule, use ->type(FOOBAR) (a lexer command), or { setType(FOOBAR); } actions that set the type. If you are using getAllTokens(), why are you parsing when you need only lex? Otherwise, use the parse tree and tree walker to assign colorization for the leaf node, and stop using getAllTokens().

Had no idea I could use tokens {}, Thanks.
I use the parser to analyze the data in the file by walking the tree.
If no tokens match the text how can I use setType() in the lexer without using a catch-all block?

If there is a token recognition error (input isn't matched by any rule), create a Error : . ; at the end of the lexer grammar (or last rule in a combined grammar). You can set the type there Error : . -> type(FOOBAR);.
